# Using this in jQuery to target only one instance of a selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying something simple in jQuery to help me get a handle on a bigger issue - I have a series of checkboxes, each inside a div

When the page loads, if the checkbox is checked I want the closest div to change colour BUT only the closest one and not the others

```
<form>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

        <input type="checkbox" class="go" checked="checked"/>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

        <input type="checkbox" class="go"/>

    </div>

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($('.go').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('.col-lg-6').css('background-color','red');
}
```

I cannot change the selectors etc nor the HTML layout - why doesn't this recognise the instanced of go and change the closest div?

In the above it doesn't do anything - if I change the jQuery to:

```
if ($('.go').is(':checked')) {
    $('.go').closest('.col-lg-6').css('background-color','red');
}
```

then it colours both div's which I don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `each` to determine which `this` will be colored parent.

For example:

```js
$('.go:checked').each(function(index, value){
 $(this).closest('.col-lg-6').css('background-color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

        <input type="checkbox" class="go" checked="checked"/>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

        <input type="checkbox" class="go"/>

    </div>

</form>
```

If theirs no condition or any other execute code you can direct do this by:

```
$('.go:checked').closest('.col-lg-6').css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense!

Comment: Happy to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

To check a group of input check or any input, you can use Jquery:

```
$('input[id='value']:checked').each(

function(index,element){

//Your changes

}


);
```

This code will iterate the checked input checkbox and you can add any code you need